# Are there guides to analysing phonetic data in R?

Tags: phonetics, reference-request, resource-request, software

I need references like papers/articles/books by and for people who [use R](http://www.r-project.org/) for analysing phonetic data. I have [Harrington's (2008) *Phonetic Analysis of Speech Corpora*](http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1405199571.html), and it's great, but a lot of other R guides are directed at researchers in applied linguistics.

What are the most appropriate references that have tips more relevant to phonetic work? Please explain **why** you're suggesting a certain resource.

Comment: Floating Tone, I fixed something in your question and now I think it works. When you see this, let me know so I can delete my comment. :)

Answer (score 9):

This is going to seem horribly self promotional, but I've gotten a lot of good feedback on a bunch of notes that I've put together, which can be found here: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/

Not all of the examples are based on phonetic data, but most of the ones from [Summer 2010](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/index.htmll#summer2010) are.

Comment: Looks really handy, thanks very much JoFrhwld!