# What are some resources that I can use to gather Twitter data for an NLP project?

Tags: nlp, computational-linguistics, corpora

I was going to use the Edinburgh Twitter Corpus that is referenced in this paper: [The Edinburgh Twitter Corpus](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/miles/papers/socmed10.pdf).  But apparently Twitter has changed their Terms and the corpus is no longer available.  Every other Twitter dataset I can find is likewise no longer available.  I am willing to start aggregating the data for myself, but it would be nice to have a set already compiled.

This is a personal, non-commercial project.

Comment: Have you come across this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/RAXyGSfZ7iQ ? I don't know the status now, after Twitter changed their T&C.

Comment: In light of what we did with [this question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/438/where-can-i-find-some-good-guides-to-analysing-phonetic-data-in-r), should we close this question?  I am concerned that it doesn't meet the "one clear answer" guideline that we try to promote.

Comment: I think it's a pretty straightforward rewording into a narrower question. Unfortunately, I don't have edit privileges.

Comment: I think it does have one clear answer and that is the answer that Alek has provided. Basically "there are no such resources because it's not allowed".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Twitter's new [Terms of Service](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms) (see paragraph (I)(4)(A)), you may not export any data retrieved from Twitter, whether through its public API or by scraping. So you will probably never find a readily-available corpus of tweets - and if you do, it's in violation. Twitter has already taken a lot of flak for essentially shutting down academic research into a whole new frontier of linguistic data.

However, if you'd like to publish your results after analysis, you may provide a database of tweet IDs and usernames, which other researchers can cross-reference with the official Twitter archive. I'd recommend the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods) to start aggregating data.